# Sketch The Region In The Plane Defined By $\lfloor x + y\rfloor^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Sketch The Region In The Plane Defined By $\lfloor x + y\rfloor^2 = 1$

I would like for you guys to have a look at my approach and give my advice regarding the solution and whether there's a different approach that you would have used.

My approach:

$\lfloor x+y\rfloor^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow \lfloor x+y\rfloor = \pm 1$

For $\lfloor x+y\rfloor =  1 \Rightarrow 1\le x + y < 2 \Leftrightarrow 1-x \leq y <2-x$

For $\lfloor x+y\rfloor =  -1 \Rightarrow -1\le x + y < 0 \Leftrightarrow -1-x \leq y <-x$

Then sketching $1-x \leq y <2-x$ and $-1-x \leq y <-x$ 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it simpler by first solving
$$\lfloor t\rfloor^2=1,$$ giving
$$t\in[-1,0[\ \cup\ [1,2[.$$
Then considering the pencil of parallel lines $x+y=t$. (If you like, the lines through $(t,0)$ and $(0,t)$).

Comment: Okay I understand, thanks Yves. No objections regarding the solution?

Comment: It's correct, obviously.

Comment: Great stuff. Cheers, Yves.